# Line break with x10^x notation ggplot title

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was able to get plots that look like the attached image by using "\n" for the line break. However, the problem is the 8.8e-14. The journal requests I change it to 8.8x10^14 (with the 14 in superscript). However, that only works if I use expression(paste). But in that case, the "\n" doesn't cause a line break anymore. I've spent about 5 hours trial and erroring through different solutions on the internet to no avail. Does anyone have a solution? Thanks in advance.

What I would like it to look like (except I would like it to say 8.8x10^14 instead):[image]

The below works EXCEPT there's no line break (I would like a line break before "Interaction")

```
plot_fun_to_revise = function(x, y) {
  ggplot(data = data_for_median_plots, aes(x = .data[[x]], y = .data[[y]], group = Secretor, linetype = Secretor)) +
    stat_summary(geom = "line", fun.data = median_hilow, size = 0.5) +
    stat_sum_df_all("median_hilow",
                    fun.args = (conf.int = 0.5),
                    linetype = "solid",
                    size = 0.5) +
    theme_classic()


lnnt_plot_median <- plot_fun_to_revise("Timepoint", "LNnT") +
        ylim(0,5000) +
        labs(y = paste("LNnT", "(\u03BCg/mL)"),
             title = expression(paste("Time p = 8.8 x", 10^-14, ", Secretor p = 0.35, Interaction p = 0.51")),
             x = "Time (months postpartum)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, I don't have your data to replicate the plot itself, but since this is about labelling anyway, let's just make an (essentially) empty plot:

```r
lnnt_plot_median <- ggplot(data.frame(x = 1, y = 1), aes(x, y)) + 
                      geom_point() +
                      theme_classic() +
                      theme(text = element_text(face = 2, size = 16),
                            plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Since you are using unicode escapes already, I think the easiest thing to do here is use the unicode escapes for superscript 1 and superscript 4:

```r
lnnt_plot_median +
 labs(y = paste("LNnT", "(\u03BCg/mL)"),
      title = paste("Time p = 8.8 x 10\u00b9\u2074,",
                    "Secretor p = 0.35,\n Interaction p = 0.51"),
      x = "Time (months postpartum)")
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! Didn't realize there was a way to do it with unicode. I really appreciate it!

Comment: I do get one weird issue -- only the bottom line (Interaction p = 0.51) is in bold. The top line isn't in bold. Even when the function has theme(text = element_text(face = 2,  size = 16)). Any ideas why this would be?